# Curl, Connection reset by peer in debian:bullseye while on debian:jessie it works

Tags: ssl, curl, openssl, debian

This is `curl` command I'm using:

`curl https://example.com --verbose --insecure`

On Debian Jessie all works good and the response code is `200`.
On Debian Bullseye it results with:

```
*   Trying 123.12.123.12:443...
* Connected to 123.12.123.12 (123.12.123.12) port 443 (#0)
* ALPN, offering h2
* ALPN, offering http/1.1
* successfully set certificate verify locations:
*  CAfile: /etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt
*  CApath: /etc/ssl/certs
* TLSv1.3 (OUT), TLS handshake, Client hello (1):
* OpenSSL SSL_connect: Connection reset by peer in connection to 123.12.123.12:443 
* Closing connection 0
curl: (35) OpenSSL SSL_connect: Connection reset by peer in connection to 123.12.123.12:443
```

What can be the difference? What is the possible solution to that?

Comment: "What can be the difference?" Different TLS handshakes based on different tools version, specially the openssl version. As you don't share the website involved, you can check yourself at https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/ for example. Other than that your question is offtopic here as not related to programming.